# Material Design - What does 'use the tint 700' mean?

Tags: android, material-design

I want my Android app to have its background color set as #F1F1F1.
The Material design guidelines suggest 'The status bar should be **the darker 700 tint** of your primary color.' What does it mean ?

Should I use #(F1*0.7)(F1*0.7)(F1*0.7) as my status bar color ?

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40964456/127923

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the color palettes on the material design spec page (http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette). Each tint in a palette has a number—that's what the **700** refers to.

Comment: Hi Justin,

Thank you for your answer. Yet I don't get what those numbers refer to ; is it some kind of darkness proportion ? In that case, 50 should be 10 times lighter than 500 ?

Regards

Comment: I don't think it's a mathematical formula; I think they are simply color categories chosen by Google that look nice together and are relatively more or less exposed or saturated.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. I'll set your answer as accepted. Thanks !

Comment: I think it is a mathematical formula. Please check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40964456/127923

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an online tool you can use to generate a material palette from a custom color. Check it out: [Material Design Palette Generator](http://mcg.mbitson.com/#/).

Your original color will be set as the **500** hue value.

Also, check out this question for a somewhat working calculation formula: [Convert colorPrimary to colorPrimaryDark (how much darker)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30870167/529138)

```
Color.colorToHSV(colorPrimary, hsv);
hsv[2] *= 0.7f;
int colorPrimaryDark = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
```

While testing, I noticed that changing the brightness value gets you close to the corresponding `colorPrimaryDark`, but it's not exactly the value that corresponds to the Google color palette.

The tool I mentioned in the beginning gets it right though.

Comment: I was able to get the same values as Material Design Palette Generator here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40964456/127923

Answer (score 0):

The material design palette provides a simple, smart approach to building with color.
Starting with the primary **500s**, it scales from light to dark offering a variety carefully chosen values.
These color ranges are then applied different elements in the UI.
The **500s** are perfect describing the dominant theme in your product and are great for toolbars.
From there, scale up to the **700s** for status bars. Or down to a **300** for secondary information.
Accent colors are brighter and more saturated.

See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYkz0Ueg0L4) for more information.