# Convert colorPrimary to colorPrimaryDark (how much darker)

Tags: java, android, material-design

In guidance with Material Design, how much darker should the statusbar be than the actionbar?
I have a color set for the actionbar at runtime and have no way of knowing this colour at programming time, so how can I get the correct statusbar colour?

I know i can darken a colour using this

```
this.getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(colorPrimary));                              
float[] hsv = new float[3];
Color.colorToHSV(colorPrimary, hsv);
hsv[2] *= 0.8f;
int colorPrimaryDark = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21)
    Chat.this.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorPrimaryDark);
```

But I'm not sure how much to darken it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official [Material Color Tool](https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=1) calculates the darkened/brightened colors based on the JS library [chroma.js](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/), using the **chroma.darken()** / **chroma.brighten()** function, whose algorithm is based on the [CIELAB color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space).

*snippet from the [source code](https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/blob/5a562f043f7b5ccfbc35db2f55ba0f1e497de63e/src/ops/darken.js#L5-L10) on Github*

```
Color.prototype.darken = function(amount=1) {
  const me = this;
  const lab = me.lab();
  lab[0] -= LAB_CONSTANTS.Kn * amount;
  return new Color(lab, 'lab').alpha(me.alpha(), true);
}
```

Material Color Tool simply uses the fallback value of the amount parameter, while the [LAB_CONSTANTS.Kn](https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/blob/5a562f043f7b5ccfbc35db2f55ba0f1e497de63e/src/io/lab/lab-constants.js#L4) is 18, it subtracts 18 (to darken) / adds 18 (to brighten) to the **lightness component L*** of the given base color.

Answer (score 13):

Material design color palette was not generated by manipulating the color in HSV. It was done with HSL (Hue, Saturation, Lightness).

Here is a utility class that will darken/lighten a color using HSL

```
package com.ammar.materialcolorizer;

import android.graphics.Color;

/**
 * A utility class for darkening and lightening colors in the same way as
 * material design color palettes
 * Created by Ammar Mardawi on 12/4/16.
 */

public class ColorUtil {

    /**
     * Darkens a given color
     * @param base base color
     * @param amount amount between 0 and 100
     * @return darken color
     */
    public static int darken(int base, int amount) {
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(base, hsv);
        float[] hsl = hsv2hsl(hsv);
        hsl[2] -= amount / 100f;
        if (hsl[2] < 0)
            hsl[2] = 0f;
        hsv = hsl2hsv(hsl);
        return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
    }

    /**
     * lightens a given color
     * @param base base color
     * @param amount amount between 0 and 100
     * @return lightened
     */
    public static int lighten(int base, int amount) {
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(base, hsv);
        float[] hsl = hsv2hsl(hsv);
        hsl[2] += amount / 100f;
        if (hsl[2] > 1)
            hsl[2] = 1f;
        hsv = hsl2hsv(hsl);
        return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
    }


    /**
     * Converts HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value) color to HSL (Hue, Saturation, Lightness)
     * Credit goes to xpansive
     * https://gist.github.com/xpansive/1337890
     * @param hsv HSV color array
     * @return hsl
     */
    private static float[] hsv2hsl(float[] hsv) {
        float hue = hsv[0];
        float sat = hsv[1];
        float val = hsv[2];

        //Saturation is very different between the two color spaces
        //If (2-sat)*val < 1 set it to sat*val/((2-sat)*val)
        //Otherwise sat*val/(2-(2-sat)*val)
        //Conditional is not operating with hue, it is reassigned!
        // sat*val/((hue=(2-sat)*val)<1?hue:2-hue)
        float nhue = (2f - sat) * val;
        float nsat = sat * val / (nhue < 1f ? nhue : 2f - nhue);
        if (nsat > 1f)
            nsat = 1f;

        return new float[]{
                //[hue, saturation, lightness]
                //Range should be between 0 - 1
                hue, //Hue stays the same

                // check nhue and nsat logic
                nsat,

                nhue / 2f //Lightness is (2-sat)*val/2
                //See reassignment of hue above
        };
    }

    /**
     * Reverses hsv2hsl
     * Credit goes to xpansive
     * https://gist.github.com/xpansive/1337890
     * @param hsl HSL color array
     * @return hsv color array
     */
    private static float[] hsl2hsv(float[] hsl) {
        float hue = hsl[0];
        float sat = hsl[1];
        float light = hsl[2];

        sat *= light < .5 ? light : 1 - light;

        return new float[]{
                //[hue, saturation, value]
                //Range should be between 0 - 1

                hue, //Hue stays the same
                2f * sat / (light + sat), //Saturation
                light + sat //Value
        };
    }
}
```

According to [Material Design Color Generator](http://mcg.mbitson.com/#/), to generate primaryColorDark, you need to darken by 12. Here is how to generate the full color palette exactly as  [Material Design Color Generator](http://mcg.mbitson.com/#/):

```
    setColor("50", ColorUtil.lighten(color, 52), mTv50);
    setColor("100", ColorUtil.lighten(color, 37), mTv100);
    setColor("200", ColorUtil.lighten(color, 26), mTv200);
    setColor("300", ColorUtil.lighten(color, 12), mTv300);
    setColor("400", ColorUtil.lighten(color, 6), mTv400);

    setColor("500", ColorUtil.lighten(color, 0), mTv500);

    setColor("600", ColorUtil.darken(color, 6), mTv600);
    setColor("700", ColorUtil.darken(color, 12), mTv700);
    setColor("800", ColorUtil.darken(color, 18), mTv800);
    setColor("900", ColorUtil.darken(color, 24), mTv900);
```

Answer (score 10):

One way of knowing exactly how much darker it should be is using [Material Color Tool](https://material.io/tools/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0). Just enter the hex value of your primary color and it will generate the light and dark versions for you.

Comment: i was looking for a way to do it programatically since i was generating the primary from an image which could have been anything. But thanks anyway, this looks like a good resource

Comment: Here is the direct link to the material color tool: https://material.io/tools/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=1&primary.color=6002ee . On the page, click the **CUSTOM** link (located near to top-right corner) and enter your hex colour to be shown the dark and light variations (and hex values) of that colour.

Answer (score 6):

> Google suggests using the 500 colors as the primary colors in your app and the other colors as accents colors.
>
> Toolbars and larger color blocks should use the 500 color of the primary color of your app.

So primaryColor should be tint 500.

> The status bar should be the darker 700 tint of your primary color.

So primaryColorDark should be tint 700.

**So I guess the primaryColorDark should be 200 tint darker than the primaryColor.**

https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html

Comment: Right. But if I know the colour code for the 500, how would i programatically convert this to a 700?

Comment: If you have your tint 500 color, you can use RGB like so: R*0.7, G*0.7, B*0.7 to get a tint 700 color I believe.

Comment: 500 and 700 are palettes, but he already had choosen the color, probably not a 500. You aren't strictly following the rules from the very first time

Comment: Guidelines are not rules. OP: take a color, use the *0.5 and *0.7 RB ratio to get a nice, MD friendly gradient. The rest is up to you, anyway.

Comment: Multiplying the RGB values by 0.7 isn't a consistent way to darken a color, and they didn't derive the 700 colors from the 500 colors this way. Depending on the color you are darkening, some colors will get darkened much more than others that way.

A better way to achieve this is to convert from rgb to the HSL color space and then subtract off from the lightness value depending on how much darker you want it to be, then convert back to rgb.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, how "darker" should it must be, it's on your own.

If you are using Android Studio, when in colors.xml, double-click in the preview of the color, switch to HSV mode, and decrease the brightness. (similar to what are you doing programmatically)

Comment: How much would i lower it though

Comment: Up to you... what you like more, what makes a good combination with your primary one. Maybe you shouldn't follow strictly the guidelines in this case, the recommendation must not work fine for all the colors

Comment: Good point, guidelines are *not* rules. But that does not really answer the question.

Comment: @shkschneider Thankfully, he has the correct answer from you. I accept that my answer is opinion-based

Answer (score 0):

Android java code:

```
public static int darkenColor(int color) {
    int alpha = Color.alpha(color);
    int red = Color.red(color);
    int green = Color.green(color);
    int blue = Color.blue(color);

    return Color.argb(alpha, (int) (red * 0.9), (int) (green * 0.9), (int) (blue * 0.9));
}

public static String intColor2String(int intColor) {
    String strColor = String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF & intColor);
    return strColor;
}
```

How to use?

```
String dakenColor = Utils.intColor2String(
        Utils.darkenColor(Color.parseColor("#21BBA6")));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer with mostly code, try to explain a little bit. How this code is working? Which advantages have this P.O.V:?