# Hexcode difference between color primary and colorPrimaryDark?

Tags: android, material-design

Is there a constant value to add to the hexcode of the Toolbar color, to derive a status bar color?

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40964456/127923

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To really stick to the guidelines, you should choose your primary and primaryDark color [among these](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette).

- colorPrimary should be one of the 500s;
- colorPrimaryDark should be one of the 700s.

I am not aware of a color relation between the two, but maybe you can guess one by looking at the examples.