# How light and dark versions of primary colors are calculated in material design components?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design

I would like to know in which sass variables we need to give the light and dark color versions of primary/secondary color. Is it automatically calculated by material by itself using some mixin? If so, is there a way to give our own colors for light and dark?

I can't see specific variables for providing light and dark color versions of primary and secondary color. There is only `@mdc-theme-primary` and `@mdc-theme-secondary` variables available.

[Here The link to gitlab](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/f310e7364f6f7a7ae162908ca27808f0e4619184/packages/mdc-theme/_variables.scss)

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to have the answer: [Convert colorPrimary to colorPrimaryDark (how much darker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870167/convert-colorprimary-to-colorprimarydark-how-much-darker)

The official Material Color Tool calculates the darkened/brightened colors based on the JS library [chroma.js](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/), using the `chroma.darken() / chroma.brighten()` function, whose algorithm is based on the CIELAB color space.